# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message | java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking xxx: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java-8, soapui, soap-client

A provider exposed a webservice, i created a java client from WSDL and i configured all certificates in cacerts and keystore for security, everything works fine on my computer, the costumer asked for deploy the client in one of their windows machine, but i couldnt make it work because of the error i get when i run the code. In this machine there is active firewall, forescout, kaspersky antivirus and a network proxy so i thought some of these could block the connection and even ping the endpoint fails (on my computer instead i dont have any of these tools, just an internet connection)
Its intresting that on the their machine **i can call the services from SOAPUI** and this makes me a bit confused. I wanna ask if someone has an idea of what can be the problem.. Thanks in advance.

```
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:305) - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationOutInterceptor@61884cb1
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (PolicyVerificationOutInterceptor.java:78) - Verified policies for outbound message.
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:305) - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor@423e4cbb
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:305) - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor@545de5a4
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:305) - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor@acb0951
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:305) - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@1d7f7be7
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (Headers.java:320) - Accept: */*
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (Headers.java:320) - Authorization: ***
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (Headers.java:320) - Connection: Keep-Alive
2020-08-30 13:18:27 DEBUG (HTTPConduit.java:1814) - No Trust Decider for Conduit '{xxx}'. An affirmative Trust Decision is assumed.
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@1d7f7be7
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor@acb0951
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor@545de5a4
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor@423e4cbb
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationOutInterceptor@61884cb1
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal@3faf2e7d
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.RPCOutInterceptor@3cfdd820
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@e25951c
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor@2e11485
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@6b0d80ed
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JStaxOutInterceptor@60dce7ea
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@452e19ca
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@64ec96c6
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor@928763c
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecurityVerificationOutInterceptor@fd8294b
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@6f8e8894
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@456d6c1e
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor@77659b30
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@1e13529a
2020-08-30 13:18:48 DEBUG (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:496) - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor@1b410b60
2020-08-30 13:18:48  WARN (LogUtils.java:475) - Interceptor for {xxx} has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.deleteBook(Unknown Source)
    at it.main.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:65)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking xxx: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1400)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1384)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:274)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1343)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1304)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1356)
    ... 12 more
2020-08-30 13:18:48 ERROR (MyMain.java:77) - javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
```

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced the same issue. After spending lot of time and searching the error in google. I have finally found a solution and it is working for me. I hope it will work for you as well.

I was able to solve it by editing the standalone-full.xml.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
    <wsdl-host>your server ip</wsdl-host>
    <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
    <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
        <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
            <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
        </pre-handler-chain>
    </endpoint-config>
</subsystem>
```

After modification I have restarted my server and WSDL file generated with my IP like below

```
<wsdl:service name="AppointmentFacadeService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:AppointmentFacadeServiceSoapBinding" name="AppointmentFacadePort">
        <soap:address location="http://server_ip:port/wsServe/AppointmentFacade"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

follow the below link for reference.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/204961